# Deserializing a class into a file and back into a list

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to deserialize a csv file into a list.
If there is a better way of sending my class' data into a file and then putting it back together into a list, please do let me know.

The class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    int studentID;
    string studentName;
    string studentAge;
}
```

The list:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.studentID = txt_sID.Text;
students.studentName = txt_sName.Text;
students.studentAge = txt_sAge.Text;
```

Serializer:

```
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"students.csv", true);
SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, students);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

Deserializer:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
using (Stream reader = new FileStream(@"students.csv", FileMode.Open))
{
    Student students2 = (Student)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    students.Add(students2);
}
```

Error:

```
XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no whitespace characters are allowed to appear before it.
```

The CSV file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Student xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <studentID>1</studentID>
  <studentName>Jonathan Joestar</studentName>
  <studentAge>21</studentAge>
</Student><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

What I have tried:

- use XmlWriter.Create as a serializer to get rid of the Xml tags. The csv file must accept multiple entries and be put back into a list, which XmlWriter.Create can only do with one entry at one time (?).

Kind regards and thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you mixing up CSV and XML? These are completely different ways of serializing data. Xml being the more general, but also more verbose way.

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't know. I'm trying to learn to put data into lists and back and this was suggested to me

Comment: As XML, your document is malformed.  It has an extra XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the end that should not be there.  There should only be one XML declaration, and should appear at the beginning of the document.  Thus the error *`XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration.`* correctly explains the problem with your document.  You can also upload your XML to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to confirm that this is the problem.  To fix this, you should fix the code that generates the malformed XML.

Comment: And you are getting the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the end because you are opening using the [`new StreamWriter(String, true)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) constructor which **appends** to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ignoring CSV and focusing on XML. CSV files essentially represents a table, and this cannot represent arbitrary object hierarchies. So in that aspect xml is more flexible.

To serialize a list of objects you should specify a list type when serializing. I.e. `List<Student>` or `Student[]`. For a complete example:

```
        [Serializable]
        public class Student
        {
            public int Id;
            public string Name;
            public float Age;

            public Student() { }
            public Student(int id, string name, float age)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
                Age = age;
            }
        }

        public void SerializeDeserialize()
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student[]));
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var students = new Student[]
            {
                new Student(1, "Bob", 42),
                new Student(2, "Alice", 22.4f)
            };
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(ms, students);
            ms.Position = 0; // Reset stream to allow it to be deserialized
            var deserialized = (Student[])xmlSerializer.Deserialize(ms);
        }
```

Replace the memory stream with a file stream you want to save to a file.

Note that while xml is perfectly fine, most of the industry are moving to [json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeCollection.htm). As far as I know json does not have any real technical advantage, so its more a issue of being less verbose and having serialization libraries that are a bit better.